# Kubernetes Ingress whitelist-source-range for LAN

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

We have a kubernetes ingress on our cluster.  We wanted to restrict access to it to only those accessing it from within our LAN (`10.0.0.0/16`).  So in the ingress annotations, I have `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "10.0.0.0/16"`.

But this allows traffic from anywhere still.  Setting it to `10.0.0.0/24` (our DHCP range), it doesn't allow any traffic at all.

When I check the nginx-ingress-controller logs, I see

> 10.0.10.1 - - [15/Oct/2019:05:40:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 2073 "-" "curl/7.54.0" 38 0.019 [wfs-ipa-8443] [] 10.0.1.2:8443 2073 0.020 200 a2d2053149dd26a490251439629134ff

This shows that it sees the source IP as the node the ingress controller pod is currently running on.  How can I make it so that it sees the source IP as either their LAN IP, or the single WAN IP we have?

Edit:

`ingress.yml`:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ipa
  namespace: wfs
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-proxy-protocol: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "off"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "10.0.0.0/16"

spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - ipa.example.com
      secretName: ipa-tls
  rules:
    - host: ipa.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: ipa
              servicePort: 8443
            path: /
```

Comment: Can you post the whole ingress.yaml?

Comment: @Crou added it in my edit.

Comment: Can you do `kubectl get -n wfs ingress ipa -o yaml` and check if k8s correctly understands the annotations?

Comment: Do you have Kubernetes on bare-metal or Managed Kubernetes Service ?
Maybe your environment supports the`externalTrafficPolicy` feature.
Look at: [Preserving the client source IP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip).

Comment: @matt_j It's on premise, and I use MetalLB for load balancing.  And yes, `externalTrafficPolicy` worked.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question probably resolved by the author, but for other community members I decided to provide an answer with a few explanations.

---

The source IP seen in the `NGINX Ingress Controller Container` is **not the original source IP of the client**. To enable preservation of the client IP set `service.spec.externalTrafficPolicy` to `Local` in the Service configuration file ( see [Preserving the client source IP documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip) ).

If you already have [kubernetes/ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/) deployed, you can use below command to configure this field:

```
$ kubectl patch svc <INGRESS_CONTROLLER_SERVICE_NAME> -p '{"spec":{"externalTrafficPolicy":"Local"}}'
```

If you would like to enable client source IP preservation during the installation of [kubernetes/ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/), add `--set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local` to the Helm install command.

Additionally, you can find useful information in this [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/).